# Can `ui` tag be merged with `user-interface`?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There are two tags which have the same meaning:

- [ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ui) (15 questions),
- [user-interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) (89 questions).

I imagine that [ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ui) may be removed, and the 15 questions retagged with [user-interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-interface).

What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree.  Merged [ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ui) into [user-interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) then made [ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ui) a tag synonym of  [user-interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-interface).

> updating post history, 20 rows affected
>   updating posts, 18 rows affected
>   updating PostTags associations, 15 rows affected
>   removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
>   updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
>   tag remapping of [user-interface] and [ui] complete!
>   remapping 0 synonyms
>   0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
>   Tag Synonym ui -> user-interface was approved!