# Make [ui] a synonym for [user-interface]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

On Super User, [ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ui) is a synonym for [user-interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-interface). 
On Meta Super User, they are [two](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/ui)
separate [tags](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-interface). 
That doesn’t make any sense. 
I recommend making [ui](/questions/tagged/ui) a synonym for [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface)
on Meta Super User.

I just discovered that this question is a duplicate of
[Can the “ui” tag be merged with “user-interface”?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/3710/150988),
but that one *says* that it’s [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) -- but it isn’t. 
(Perhaps it got reverted in the intervening two years.)

Answer (score 2):

Synonymized and merged!

Thanks for letting us know.